# Receiving NaN when trying to make calculations using numbers retrieved from textboxes in JS

Tags: javascript, calculator, nan

I am trying to make a simple calculator in javascript. Whenever I click the add, subtract, multiply, or divide buttons, however, I get the result NaN. I know that the numbers are successfully retrieved, however, because I am able to alert(input1, input2) if I put that code in. I don't understand why it doesn't let me operate on the two variables, however. I do not receive any errors in the JS console.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css" />
  <script>
    var input1, input2

    function getNumbers() {
      input1 = Number(document.getElementById("imp1").value);
      input2 = Number(document.getElementById("imp2").value);
    }

    function sum(input1, input2) {
      getNumbers();
      var sum = input1 + input2;
      alert(sum);
    }

    function diff(input1, input2) {
      getNumbers();
      var diff = input1 - input2;
      alert(diff);
    }

    function prod(input1, input2) {
      getNumbers();
      var prod = input1 * input2;
      alert(prod);


    }

    function quot(input1, input2) {
      getNumbers();
      var quot = input1 / input2;
      alert(quot);
    }
  </script>


  <div id="calc">
    <form name="calc_input">
      <input type="text" id="imp1" />
      <input type="text" id="imp2" />
      <!-- buttons -->
      <button onclick="sum()" id="add" value="sum">Add</button>
      <button onclick="diff()" id="subtract" value="diff">Subtract</button>
      <button onclick="prod()" id="multiply" value="prod">Multiply</button>
      <button onclick="quot()" id="divide" value="quot">Divide</button>

    </form>
  </div>

</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function sum(input1, input2) {` This is causing issue.

Here params will take precedence over global variable and as you are not passing any value, they will remain `undefined` and hence `NaN`

All you have to do is remove these arguments as you wish to use global variables.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css" />
  <script>
    var input1, input2

    function getNumbers() {
      input1 = Number(document.getElementById("imp1").value);
      input2 = Number(document.getElementById("imp2").value);
    }

    function sum() {
      getNumbers();
      var sum = input1 + input2;
      alert(sum);
    }

    function diff() {
      getNumbers();
      var diff = input1 - input2;
      alert(diff);
    }

    function prod() {
      getNumbers();
      var prod = input1 * input2;
      alert(prod);


    }

    function quot() {
      getNumbers();
      var quot = input1 / input2;
      alert(quot);
    }
  </script>


  <div id="calc">
    <form name="calc_input">
      <input type="text" id="imp1" />
      <input type="text" id="imp2" />
      <!-- buttons -->
      <button onclick="sum()" id="add" value="sum">Add</button>
      <button onclick="diff()" id="subtract" value="diff">Subtract</button>
      <button onclick="prod()" id="multiply" value="prod">Multiply</button>
      <button onclick="quot()" id="divide" value="quot">Divide</button>

    </form>
  </div>

</head>

</html>
```

#### Alternate approach

- You can remove global variables and return an array of numbers from `getNumbers`. By making a generic pattern to fetch inputs using a composite selector and not IDs, you can *add/remove* any number of inputs.
- You can have a generic function that will process the inputs as structure for all are same.
- Accept operator and process accordingly.

```js
function getNumbers() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('form[name="calc_input"] input[type="text"]');
  var nums = [];
  for(var i = 0; i< inputs.length; i++){
    nums.push(Number(inputs[i].value))
  }
  return nums;
}

function operate(operator){
  var nums = getNumbers();
  var result = nums.reduce(function(p,c){
    switch(operator){
      case "+": return p+c;
      case "-": return p-c;
      case "*": return p*c;
      case "/": return p/c
    }
  })
  alert(result);
}
```

```html
<div id="calc">
  <form name="calc_input">
    <input type="text" id="imp1" />
    <input type="text" id="imp2" />
    <!-- buttons -->
    <button onclick="operate('+')" id="add" value="sum">Add</button>
    <button onclick="operate('-')" id="subtract" value="diff">Subtract</button>
    <button onclick="operate('*')" id="multiply" value="prod">Multiply</button>
    <button onclick="operate('/')" id="divide" value="quot">Divide</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: how could I fix this? The value cannot be passed until a user has entered one in. Do I have to run this code only after the user has entered their values, through use of an if statement?

Comment: @alec935 Don't specify parameters if you're not using them. So just `function sum()` and so on.

Comment: @alec935 Please check the updated code. I have added an alternate approach for more generic structure. Hope it helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your all variable into integer.. it display now as a string thats why its not calculate as you want.here is code you may check...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css" />
  <script>


    function sum(input1, input2) {
      input1 = Number(document.getElementById("imp1").value);
  input2 = Number(document.getElementById("imp2").value);
      var sum = parseInt(input1) + parseInt(input2);
      alert(sum);
    }


  </script>


  <div id="calc">
    <form name="calc_input">
      <input type="text" id="imp1" />
      <input type="text" id="imp2" />
      <!-- buttons -->
      <button onclick="sum()" id="add" value="sum">Add</button>
      <button onclick="diff()" id="subtract" value="diff">Subtract</button>
      <button onclick="prod()" id="multiply" value="prod">Multiply</button>
      <button onclick="quot()" id="divide" value="quot">Divide</button>

    </form>
  </div>

</head>

</html>
```

Comment: I still get the same "Nan"

Comment: @alec935 i updated my js please check and try again demo link https://jsfiddle.net/1z45x8c9/